# Only one user could not update a record in table

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I am trying to update invoice status. Everything works fine except there is only 1 user who could not update it. The thing is that the problem is very random.

For example: This user A, when he runs the job to update invoice status for 4 invoices call invoice 1, 2, 3, 4. The status of invoice 1 and 3 are not updated. When he rerun the second time, the status of invoice 1, 4 are not updated. However, when I asks user B(exact same privileges) to run, everything works fine. I even create a new user to try, and everything works fine too. When i check the table, for this user A the record that are not updated have the recversion value set to 1, while for other users, the record have the recversion value set to random number.

Base on this article http://daxdude.blogspot.sg/2013/02/ax-issue-cannot-edit-record-in-sales.html , it is a concurrency problem, but when i check my code, i have the "forupdate" keyword:

```
select firstonly forupdate InvoiceStatus
        from custTransSummary
        where custTransSummary.RecId == invoiceSummaryRecId;
```

I also try to following this link: http://daxdude.blogspot.sg/2013/11/dynamics-ax-2012-resetclear-your-users.html
to clear the user cache data by go to File > Tools > Option, then select Usage Data. But it still does not solve the problem

Can anyone help me point out how could I go to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this a custom process? Look at `pessimisticLock` for a concurrency model if it's an update conflict. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190073.aspx . When you cleared the usage data, did you do it for the USER having the issue and not your own user? You need to do that as their user.

Comment: Yes, it is a customization. On the table, I have property "OccEnabled" set to yes

Comment: Did you clear usage data for the affected user and not yourself?

Comment: Yes, I did clear the usage cache for the affected user.

Comment: Try pessimisticLock. Use the debugger to step through the code. Try restarting the AOS.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am going to do now. Also, about the cache, should I do another way which is to delete the .auc file from users\\Appdata\ folder on the affected user's laptop?

Comment: You can try that. Also the *.kti file.

Comment: Delete the users .AUC file? https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axaptavsme/archive/2015/04/26/how-to-delete-auc-files

Comment: Could you show more of your update code? The select statement looks suspicious to me because you are using a field list to only select the `InvoiceStatus` field. If you want to update that record, you should not use a field list. If you just use the `InvoiceStatus` to update another record, you should not use `forupdate`.

Comment: Hi all, clearing the .AUC files seem to do the work. The problem got resolved

Comment: @MarkoSalonen: Maybe make that an answer?

Comment: @jacky-nguyen Mark as answer?

Comment: @MarkoSalonen: can you create an answer below the question, then i'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: @jacky-nguyen .AUC file deletion I wrote on May 13 at 5:52, above.

Comment: @MarkoSalonen: how do I mark a comment as an answer? I just up voted your comment. Can you post an answer, from there I can mark it as answered.

Comment: @jacky-nguyen My bad, I thought that you can mark a comment as an answer, but apparently not, which is a bummer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the users .AUC file from disk? https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axaptavsme/archive/2015/04/26/how-to-delete-auc-files